Lerna v8 not publishing on GitLab CI/CD
I am implement lerna v8 for my monorepo configuration. I need to publish my new changes in the gitlab registry for our organization. The issue is I am getting an error from the pipeline CI/CD when lerna is trying the version or publish command. (is the same error as below for both)

lerna version --yes
/builds/my-org/ui/react-widgets/node_modules/fs-minipass/lib/index.js:136
[_handleChunk] (br, buf) {
^
TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
at Object. (/builds/my-org/ui/react-widgets/node_modules/fs-minipass/lib/index.js:136:4)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1364:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1422:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1203:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1019:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1231:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:177:18)
at Object. (/builds/my-org/ui/react-widgets/node_modules/npm-registry-fetch/node_modules/cacache/lib/content/read.js:4:13)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1364:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1422:10)
Node.js v18.20.3

I tried to use lerna with npx, running from scripts and installing lerna globally in the container for the stage but the error in console is always the same.
